# Subplot Squeeze

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use subplot but have them squeeze together, how to make enough room for each subplot vertically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tight layout may solve your problem. It adjusts subplots' parameters to fit in the area. You can glance over
[Tight Layout guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).